# Manage Docker Images in Azure App Services for Staging and Production

Tags: azure, docker, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am setting up two Django Web App on the Azure using their App Services - one for staging and one for production.

I have dockerized my Django App and stored the image in the Azure Container Registries.

Now, I have noticed that when I create the webapp, it asks for the specific tag from the registry repo that I want to use, which **I can't seem to change** after the webapp is created.

My plan is to tag the images with their versions (e.g. `:090920201`) and promote this version (tag) first on staging, test it there and if it works as expected, use the same version (tag) image and promote it on prod.

For now, I am tagging the images as `:staging` for staging environment and `:prod` for the production environment. When I am happy with a specific version of my local, I push the image with their respective tags.

Now the problem is since I cannot change the tag of the registry repo after the app is created, I have to push the same image twice, one with `:staging` tag and if this image is working as expected, push the same image again with the `prod` tag.

This could work for the time being, until the dev and staging are in sync.

So what's the problem?

- Is there a way to change the tag of the image after the web app was created in Azure?
- Is there a way to use a consistent tag (let's say `:latest`) but only deploy to staging first, test there and then promote it to production?
- If we completely ignore what I am doing, how else do you suggest I utilize the same image and manage the promotion of the image first on the staging, and then to the production environment?

Apologies for the world tour for a straight forward question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you looked at [registry best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-best-practices#repository-namespaces), but you can't retag an image after it's been deployed.

You can consider tagging your images by including the slots in the namespace name e.g. `<registry-name>.azurecr.io/<app-svc-slot>/<image-name>:<version>`. If you're going to use the `latest` moniker, I would tag latest `docker build` twice, the actual release version and latest. You can then push both images to your registry, or just the one tagged `latest`, like what's explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-image-tag-version.